# How to write a custom Datamapper adapter?

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

I am trying to write a simple Datamapper adapter that will be used to query an HTTP API. I spent quite some time trying to find some documentation, but everything seemed to be quite old (appart from a Taiwanese Ruby Conf in Chinese...).

Which methods do we need to override ?

It looks like I only have to subclass an `AbstractAdapter` and override the `create`, `read`, `update` and `delete` methods, but not sure what arguments they are supposed to take and what they are supposed to return.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following page which includes a list of contributed datamapper adapters:

https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/wiki/Adapters

There are several in the list that interact with web services that may serve as good examples.  For example, checkout the sales force datamapper adapter.